# Join Two relations in Pig and retrieve required data

Tags: apache-pig

File 1:

```
EmpID   Name  DOB  SAL  
122292|ABCDEF|1985|60000  
122293|GHIJKL|1988|75000
```

File 2:

```
EmpID Agreeno POLNO      
122292|UNI456|AWS12345     
122292|UNI457|AWS12346     
122292|UNI458|AWS12347     
122292|UNI459|AWS12348     
122293|UNI460|AWS12349     
122293|UNI461|AWS12350     
122293|UNI462|AWS12351     
122293|UNI463|AWS12352
```

Expecting the Result Set in the File 3 as follows,

File 3:

Need Employee details, and Employee agreement details in sequential order as below for each employee.

```
122292|ABCDEF|1985|60000
122292|UNI456|AWS12345
122292|UNI457|AWS12346
122292|UNI458|AWS12347
122292|UNI459|AWS12348
122293|GHIJKL|1988|75000
122293|UNI460|AWS12349 
122293|UNI461|AWS12350 
122293|UNI462|AWS12351 
122293|UNI463|AWS12352
```

I want to do this in Pig. Is there any other way (Hive/MR, etc) which we can achieve the same result other than Pig?

I was trying to use JOIN LEFT OUTER commands in Pig. But couldn't achieve.

Appreciate your response on this.

Comment: you want to use union by the looks of things

Answer (score 0):

You can't really achieve the output you want (in that exact format) because of how Pig handles relations.  What would the schema of `File 3` be?  All of the rows don't have the same fields and this is something that Pig expects.

```
-- F1 is File 1
-- F2 is File 2

-- If order does matter for File 2, then you are going to need to RANK the data
-- right of the bat because most Pig operations do not preserve order.
-- This means you will have to carry the first field of F2_R in later operations,
-- and use F2_R in place of F2.

-- F2_R = RANK F2 ;

G = GROUP F2 BY EmpID ;
H = FOREACH G GENERATE group AS EmpID, F2.(Agreeno, POLNO) AS agree_details ;

J = JOIN F1 BY EmpID LEFT, H BY EmpID ;
-- Now, the output of J should look like:
-- (122292,ABCDEF,1985,60000,122292,{(UNI456,AWS12345),(UNI457,AWS12346),(UNI458,AWS12347),(UNI459,AWS12348)})
-- etc.
```

`J` is how you will likely want to represent `File 3` in Pig. This way stores the contents of `File 2` as a bag.  If you really need for the output to be completely flat, then you will have to use a `FLATTEN` on `agree_details` after `J`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. But my Elastic Search team wants the data in the below format.